# Typescript: prevent using Interfaces with undefined values as right hand side values

Tags: typescript

I want to accomplish the following:

Let's say I have this:

```
interface Foo {
    bar: number
    bas: string
}

let foo = {} as Foo;
foo.bar = 123;
```

How can I ensure that all members of my Interface have non-null values on compile-time?
e.g. something like:

```
let x = foo.bas;
```

Should result in a error.

I know that possible implementation would be via constructor but I have many interfaces that in fact serve as self-documentation for API and I don't want to change them all (or can I create a base class for them all that could ensure non-undefinedness for all members)?

Of course I can do the following:

```
let x : Foo = {
bar: 1
bas: 'x'
}
```

But what if I don't know `bas` just yet and I purposely want it to be undefined because I will know `bas` later but I want to catch the fact that I forgot to initialize `bas` early at compile time at the line when I access `bas`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using a cast. In this direction, there is nothing you can do.
Using a cast in the way you do is circumventing a lot of Typescripts checks, because you are basically telling it to ignore the errors. You are giving it an object that obviously does NOT match the contract and then you are telling it to treat is as if it would match the contract. So it does exactly that.

However, you can instead use a declared variable of the interface type:

```
let foo: Foo = {
  bar: 123
}; // will result in an error, because bas is required.
```

Regarding your update:
That is not possible. Either the variable matches the contract or it doesn't. The check happens at assignment, not at usage of a property.

Comment: Thank you! I remembered about this case but I made a edit to my original question that eliminates this particular case

Comment: Updated the answer